# iOS Mapkit location URL

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios11

I want to display the user current location in an url using mapkit.
I know that it can be done with google maps, but it can be done using Apple own mapkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the url has to follow some pattern. Apple has a documentation on how it can be done: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html